I have a problem with terminal applications for Android
I wrote a code in C++ and with ncurses in an IDE for Android to test it on the terminal. The problem is when I use a different terminal.
I used c4droid to compile the code with the option to export binary instead of apk; the default c4droid terminal runs it without problems. The problem is that when I use a different terminal, for example, when using the Jackpal Terminal Emulator application for Android, the code does not work and the terminal says, "Error opening terminal: screen" and with root permissions on the phone, it says, "Error opening terminal: vt100" It should be said that when compiling a code with only C++ without using Ncurses with the option to export binary instead of apk of C4Droid, the C4Droid terminal and any other terminal run it and do not cause any problems.
Is there any solution to fix the Error opening terminal: screen issue on Android?
I want the code to work and run on other terminals.
The code is very basic and still causes the error. This is the code:
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();
    start_color();
    refresh();
    printw("Hello World");
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}


I'm not sure how to explain the error further.
The only problem is when I try to run the code on different terminals.

Question is good now. I can't answer it, but folks more experienced with Droids should be able to.
